# How to prevent contenteditable from being passed down to children

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the following snippet, when a `<div>` becomes contenteditable, all the children inside is, including other `<div>` child elements, become contenteditable too and there seems to be no way from this to happen.

I'd like to put ***read-only*** `<div>` elements inside a content-editable `<div>`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `contenteditable = false` in child elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting content editable false on your children:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>You can edit me</p>
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
    <p contenteditable="false">You can't edit me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>test</p>
    <p contenteditable="false">test </p>
</div>
```

you can use this code